# finding and storing values from string

Tags: php

I have a string which looks something like this:

```
$fetched = name=myName zip=420424 country=myCountry; 
// and so on, it is not an array
```

I fetch these values from an api.

I want only the zip=873289 (infact only the numbers).

So I use:

```
// $fetched above is the output of the function below
$fetched = file_get_contents("http://example.com");
```

This way I fetch the contents and can match it with this code

```
$zip = preg_match ('/zip=[0-9]+/', $fetched );
```

But I want to store it in the variable, what is function to store the matched results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to indicate the part you want to capture with parentheses, then supply an extra parameter to preg_match to pick these up:

```
$matches=array();
if (preg_match ('/zip=([0-9]+)/', $fetched, $matches ))
{
    $zip=$matches[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) stores its result in the third argument, which is passed [by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). So instead of:

```
$zip = preg_match ('/zip=[0-9]+/', $fetched);
```

You should have:

```
preg_match ('/zip=[0-9]+/', $fetched, $zip);
```